# Visual Studio WPF project migration

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, migration

I created a Visual Studio 2015 WPF project on a Windows 7 x86 machine. The platform target is "Any CPU" but the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox is checked. The code compiles and the WPF application works.

Then I installed Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 machine and copied the whole VS solution folder to the new machine.

Now it seems like VS2015 does not recognize that the project is a WPF project any more. I get errors like

`The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context`

or

`'AddService' does not contain a definition for 'sLAModelText' and no extension method 'sLAModelText' accepting a first argument of type 'AddService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

in the .xaml.cs files of all my WPF windows.

No namespace or class names changed when I copied the VS solution. I only had to delete and re-add the reference to Microsoft.Office.Core.

Also, the new machine does not have a connection to the internet. I don't know if this might change anything.

Any ideas anyone?

---

Edit1: Also, I get a Warning

`Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'`

---

Edit2: When on the old machine, I added a few dlls to the project, could it be that these are explicitly for x86? But then why would VS2015 not recognize the WPF project? These dlls are:

```
Microsoft.Office.Client.Education.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
Microsoft.SharePointClientRuntime.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel-WPF.dll
MigraDoc.Rendering-WPF.dll
MigraDoc.RtfRendering-WPF.dll
PdfSharp.Charting-WPF.dll
PdfShart-WPF.dll
```

Comment: Check .Net version on both systems and in you project's target settings, it might be different from the one you have on server. If it's a small project you could try deletion of solution file, or even recreate project and add existent stuff in it. And check which system target's you libs, and mb try to set you project for x86 explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what caused my problem:

After checking the .net version and other settings I surrendered and just created a new WPF project in VS2015 on the x64 machine, added new WPF windows and classes and just pasted the code. I had to add a view references and in the end, only the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll` was missing. I had to extract it from `C:\\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\` and manually added it to my project's references.

So when looking at the old project (x86) all I had to do was also to add the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll` to the project and it compiled correctly. The odd thing is, though, that I hadn't received any error on a missing reference.